# Bash script for usb controller connection output?

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, output

I have a bash script that configures my USB controller to act like an Xbox 360 controller for use with Steam. Here is the current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
lsmod | grep xpad

sudo xboxdrv --evdev /dev/input/event14 --evdev-absmap ABS_X=x1,ABS_Y=y1,ABS_RX=x2,ABS_RZ=y2,ABS_HAT0X=dpad_x,ABS_HAT0Y=dpad_y --axismap -Y1=Y1,-Y2=Y2 --evdev-keymap BTN_TOP=x,BTN_TRIGGER=y,BTN_THUMB2=a,BTN_THUMB=b,BTN_BASE3=back,BTN_BASE4=start,BTN_TOP2=lb,BTN_PINKIE=rb,BTN_BASE=lt,BTN_BASE2=rt,BTN_BASE5=tl,BTN_BASE6=tr --mimic-xpad --silent &

exit 0
```

I would like to add some sort of "if" "else" statement to say that if the script is successful then notify me that it worked.
But I don't know how I would do it.

e.g

if "script runs fine"
then notify-send -t 2000 USB controller connection successful
else "do nothing"

My questions are:

1.Would I need 2 seperate scripts? i.e one to run the first, the other to read the output of that script and produce the notification, or can I do it all in the same script?

2.How do I read that output?

Generally after it has created the new event in the terminal after the script runs, it will tell me the new event number (usually event15). If not it flags up an error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a read here http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Answer (score 0):

script 1

```
#!/bin/bash
lsmod | grep xpad

sudo xboxdrv --evdev /dev/input/event14 --evdev-absmap ABS_X=x1,ABS_Y=y1,ABS_RX=x2,ABS_RZ=y2,ABS_HAT0X=dpad_x,ABS_HAT0Y=dpad_y --axismap -Y1=Y1,-Y2=Y2 --evdev-keymap BTN_TOP=x,BTN_TRIGGER=y,BTN_THUMB2=a,BTN_THUMB=b,BTN_BASE3=back,BTN_BASE4=start,BTN_TOP2=lb,BTN_PINKIE=rb,BTN_BASE=lt,BTN_BASE2=rt,BTN_BASE5=tl,BTN_BASE6=tr --mimic-xpad --silent &
```

script 2

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(/path/to/script1)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    #do something
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - just one last question, sorry.

This appears that the script reads the exit status and if the script exits successfully then produce the outcome (correct me if I'm wrong I'm new to this).

I would like it to read the outcome of the script as this: 


If after running the script, the outcome displays the words,

Your xbox controller is now configured to /dev/input/event15, press ctrl-c to quit

Then

notify me that it was succesful,


if the outcome of the script says

Device or resource busy

then

notify me that it failed

Sorry if this makes no sense.

Comment: Is it necessary to run xboxdrv command in background? How long is it gonna take?

Comment: I could probably just run the command once to be honest. It is only used to create the new event. I just wanted it to notify me as I have created it into a menu item instead of running from terminal. It's more of a learning thing for me. I enjoy creating scripts but my knowledge is very limited. I really appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
lsmod | grep xpad

command1="sudo xboxdrv --evdev /dev/input/event14 --evdev-absmap ABS_X=x1,ABS_Y=y1,ABS_RX=x2,ABS_RZ=y2,ABS_HAT0X=dpad_x,ABS_HAT0Y=dpad_y --axismap -Y1=Y1,-Y2=Y2 --evdev-keymap BTN_TOP=x,BTN_TRIGGER=y,BTN_THUMB2=a,BTN_THUMB=b,BTN_BASE3=back,BTN_BASE4=start,BTN_TOP2=lb,BTN_PINKIE=rb,BTN_BASE=lt,BTN_BASE2=rt,BTN_BASE5=tl,BTN_BASE6=tr --mimic-xpad --silent"

command2="notify-send -t 2000 USB controller connection successful" #Your command here. 

output=$(command1) && [ echo $output | grep -q "Replace this with your success output" ] && $command &
```

Comment: I don't know if this will make any more sense but when the 1st script is run, it produces either of 2 results, If it is successful it tells me it has saved the new event to /dev/input/event15 then says Press Ctrl-c to quit. If it is unsuccessful it says "Device or resource busy". These results are only after the script is run. So my idea was to grep the results of it and then notify me. But it does nothing. This is what I made, but as I say. It does nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
lsmod | grep xpad

command1=$(sudo xboxdrv --evdev /dev/input/event14 --evdev-absmap ABS_X=x1,ABS_Y=y1,ABS_RX=x2,ABS_RZ=y2,ABS_HAT0X=dpad_x,ABS_HAT0Y=dpad_y --axismap$

command2=$(notify-send -t 2000 USB controller connection successful) #Your command here. 

output=$(command1) && [ echo $output | grep -q "Press Ctrl-c to quit" ] && $command2 &

exit 0
```

Comment: Hi t_thirupathi - I tried your edited version and got /joypad.sh: line 8: command1: command not found, I also tried the above and got no results sorry